# Flutter Web download file from url instead of opening it

Tags: flutter, web, download, progressive-web-apps

Is there any way to get files like `.pdf` downloaded directly on user's device instead of opening this pdf in the browser?
This code works for downloading non browser supported files but it opens pdf, mp3, etc. in the browser.

```
final anchor = AnchorElement(
    href: pickedFile)
  ..setAttribute("download", fileName)
    ..click();
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still searching for solution.Here is what I have done.

Anchor tag will directly download file if it has **download** attribute.

> Note: Download attribute is only supported for same-origin request

So instead of assigning external URL link to anchor element. Create Blob object from PDF data and create Object URL from that.

```
 var url = Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(Blob([data]));
      AnchorElement(href: url)
        ..setAttribute('download', '<downloaded_file_name.pdf>')
        ..click();
```

I am using Firebase to store file so here is the complete code.

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(resumeFileName).getData().then(
    (data) {
      var url = Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(Blob([data]));
      AnchorElement(href: url)
        ..setAttribute('download', '<downloaded_file_name.pdf>')
        ..click();
    }
  );
```

Comment: Which flutter package contains `Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob`?

Comment: @markhorrocks I am used following import 

`import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html`
and update usage as following.
`html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(html.Blob([data])); `

Answer (score 0):

by following the steps below, you can download the file automatically by the browser and save it in the download directory.

- In this method, [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) packages are used.
- The important thing is to manage Multiplatform-Mode and using this code, is better you create 3 separate dart files.

1. switch_native_web.dart
2. web.dart
3. native.dart

```
/// switch_native_web.dart 
import 'native.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'web.dart' as switch_value;

class SwitchNativeWeb {
   static void downloadFile({required String url,
   required String fileName ,required String dataType}){
           switch_value.downloadFile(dataType: dataType,fileName: fileName,url: url);}
 }
```

...

```
    /// web.dart
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as universal_html;
    

Future<void> downloadFile(
    {required String url,
    required String fileName,
    required String dataType}) async {
  try {
    // first we make a request to the url like you did
    // in the android and ios version
    final http.Response r = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
    );

    // we get the bytes from the body
    final data = r.bodyBytes;
    // and encode them to base64
    final base64data = base64Encode(data);

    // then we create and AnchorElement with the html package
    final a =
        universal_html.AnchorElement(href: '$dataType;base64,$base64data');

    // set the name of the file we want the image to get
    // downloaded to
    a.download = fileName;

    // and we click the AnchorElement which downloads the image
    a.click();
    // finally we remove the AnchorElement
    a.remove();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

...

```
  /// native.dart
  Future<void> downloadFile({required String url, required String fileName,
     required String dataType}) async {}
```

And using the following sample code for calling the downloadFile method wherever you need:

```
...
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => SwitchNativeWeb.downloadFile(
                url: "https://... your url ..../download.jpg",
                fileName: "download.jpg",
                dataType: "data:image/jpeg"),
            child: Text('download')
    )
...
```

I only wrote the code related to web download (according to the question), you can write the code related to ios and android download in the native .dart file.

Answer (score -2):

Use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) Library.

```
dependencies:
  dio: ^3.0.10
```

to download file

```
response = await dio.download("https://www.google.com/", "./xx.html");
```

this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV7cIsh2S1M) will help you.

Comment: You don't get the question. It's about Flutter Web